# Objective-C common object initialisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

In Objective-C (well, Cocoa/Cocoa Touch), it seems common for objects to have many initialisers. In other languages, I've been used to having one place I can override to affect object initialisation, but I see no way to avoid code like the below:

```
- (void)commonInit
{
    // Do stuff
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) [self commonInit];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) [self commonInit];
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) [self commonInit];
    return self;
}
```

(in this case to perform some common initilisation task on a `UIView` subclass).

Is there a better way? Hopefully there is: being forced to type out every method is quite tedious.

Comment: Nope; looks good to me, except I would make the `commonInit` *private* and use a leading underscore to demonstrate that.

Comment: Looks good, but you can also use [The Designated Initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MultipleInitializers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use category option to do this.

.h file

```
@interface UIImage (CommonInit)
- (void)commonInit;
@end
```

.m file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "UIView+CommonInit.h"

@implementation UIView (trans)
- (void)commonInit; {
    //... do your stuff
}
@end
```

Now it can be possible with your code as below

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) [self commonInit];
    return self;
}
```

Just import this file in wherever you want or If you want to all means, just import it into `YourProject-Prefix.pch` file.

Comment: Same as making `commonInit` *private* with `@interface MyClass ()`.

Comment: Ya I accept it with trojanfoe. But He specifically asked about subclass. That is he may have more than class which have subclass of this.

Comment: Since `commonInit` is an implementation detail, the API shall not be public. Putting it into a _private_ Category in order to organize code is IMHO a bit exaggerated. A simple helper method will do it as well. However, I would strongly discourage from the practice to put a custom header into the pch file! In the pch file there belong only system headers. Only in _rare cases_ headers of third party libraries if there are nasty subtleties and conflicts if a certain include order is not maintained (e.g. including boost headers and Foundation).